# Simple Injector and MVVM Null object reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, simple-injector

First off, new with MVVM and WPF, building up my first application following MVVM. I tried to find answers on the internet but without any results, so decided to ask here.

I have the following constructor in my MainWindow:

```
container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

container.Register<IContext, ApplicationContext>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
            container.Register<SearchOrderViewModel>();

_searchOrderViewModel = container.GetInstance<SearchOrderViewModel>();

NavigationCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnNavigation);
```

And then I use a button with Command to set the Content to ContentControl in XML with this:

```
private void OnNavigation(string destination)
        {
            switch (destination)
            {
                case "orderSearch":
                    CurrentViewModel = _searchOrderViewModel;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And finally my SearchOrderViewModel constructor

```
private IContext InstanceContext;


public SearchOrderViewModel(IContext applicationContext)
{
       InstanceContext = applicationContext;

}
```

My problem is that when the CurrentView changes to the SearchOrderViewModel, its returning System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' from InitializeComponent() in SearchOrderView.xaml which basically is:

```
public partial class SearchOrderView : UserControl
    {
        public SearchOrderView()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); <----- Exception happens here
        }
    }
```

Stack Trace if helps:

```
 at System.DefaultBinder.BindToMethod(BindingFlags bindingAttr, MethodBase[] match, Object[]& args, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo cultureInfo, String[] names, Object& state)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.DynamicMethodRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(Type type, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.DynamicMethodRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
```

I cant figure out on my own whats wrong with it and spend few hours, but I am out of ideas. I am hoping someone can provide some information whats going wrong ?

EDIT:: If I remove public IContext applicationContextSearch from OrderViewModel(IContext applicationContext) is working, but I cannot pass my application context...

Comment: I could never get dependency injection to work with code behind in WPF, take a look at MVVM Light for a really good framework/starting project with dependency injection.

Comment: Can you show the xaml of SearchOrderView?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue sounds like this it is in `ApplicationContext`, have you checked the constructor and seen if you are hitting it? It seams that maybe it has some decencies that are not registered.

Comment: On initialization _searchOrderViewModel = container.GetInstance<SearchOrderViewModel>() I am hitting it yes

Comment: Is there a dependency in ApplicationConext? and are you hitting the constructor in  ApplicationConext?

Comment: Its an interface, yes its hitting it. I want to pass that Application Context to the user control

Comment: i understand that, my question is `IContext` should = `ApplicationContext` because of `container.Register<IContext, ApplicationContext>(Lifestyle.Singleton);` inside Application context does this have a constructor? if so is it being hit? if so are there depencies in it a that need to be registered?

Answer (score 0):

It was the XAML, I re-wired it from scratch and started working, for some reason was not able to find my ViewModel.

Found that by modifying my Exception Settings and then proper exception popped up.